# Estimator maximizing pvalue of Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

Tags: estimation, p-value, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

Suppose we have some reasonable distribution known up to some unknown parameter $θ$ and sample $X_1$, $X_2$, ..., $X_n$ from that distribution. For each possible candidate parameter $\hat{θ}$ we can compute the p-value of Kolmogorov-Smirnov test for this sample and our distribution with parameter $\hat{θ}$. What if we chose such $\hat{θ}=\hat{θ}_{KS}$ so that this p-value is maximal? What are the properties of such estimator? One can easily see that it will be consistent (at least for some reasonable distributions) but can we deduce some more properties like asymptotic normality or even asymptotic efficiency? Is it even reasonable to use such estimator?

Comment: I believe the answers will all depend heavily on this one-parameter distribution family, so if you have a particular problem in mind, it would be well to disclose more details.

Comment: @whuber This problem arose when I was thinking about estimation of Beta distribution parameters (with $\alpha=\beta$).